# create the PaymentMethodCreateParams manually stripe

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to collect payments. Instead of using the CardInputWidget I decided to use the built in inputs that stripe has such as stripe.android.view.CardNumberEditText, stripe.android.view.CVCEditText, stripe.android.view.ExpiryDateEditText, and stripe.android.view.PostalCodeEditText. My only issue is that I know I will have to create the PaymentMethodCreateParams manually but I don't know how I will go about it. As of right now I have everything setup for the card Input wiget in my java code. Can someone help me with this and tell/show me how I will go about this. Thanks in advance

```
//Paymentpage.activity

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/offwhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">





    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"



        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/Base.CardView"
        >

        <!--
        <com.stripe.android.view.CardMultilineWidget
            android:id="@+id/cardInputWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/StripeDefaultTheme"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

            -->


        <com.stripe.android.view.CardNumberEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="Card Number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.stripe.android.view.ExpiryDateEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="Expiration date"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.stripe.android.view.CvcEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <com.stripe.android.view.PostalCodeEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="Postal code"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/payButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/faux_dukes_shade2"
            android:text="Pay"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardInputWidget"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardInputWidget"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardInputWidget" />


    </LinearLayout>

    
//Paymentpage.java

 private void startCheckout() {

        //amount will calculate from .00 make sure multiply by 100
        //double amount=Double.parseDouble(mAmount.getText().toString())*1;

        // Create a PaymentIntent by calling the sample server's /create-payment-intent endpoint.
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");

/*
        String json = "{"
                + "\"currency\":\"usd\","
                + "\"items\":["
                + "{\"id\":\"photo_subscription\"}"
                + "]"
                + "}";


 */

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String t = intent.getStringExtra("days");

        int in = Integer.valueOf(t);

        String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();





        double amount=in*100;
        Map<String,Object> payMap=new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,Object> itemMap=new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String,Object>> itemList =new ArrayList<>();
        payMap.put("currency","usd");
        payMap.put("receipt_email",email.toString());
        itemMap.put("id","photo_subscription");
        itemMap.put("amount",amount);
        itemList.add(itemMap);
        payMap.put("items",itemList);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(payMap);





        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BACKEND_URL + "create-payment-intent")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        httpClient.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new PayCallback(this));




        // Hook up the pay button to the card widget and stripe instance
        //Button payButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        payButton.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
            PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
            if (params != null) {
                Map<String, String> extraParams = new HashMap<>();
                extraParams.put("setup_future_usage", "off_session");

                ConfirmPaymentIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmPaymentIntentParams
                        .createWithPaymentMethodCreateParams(params, paymentIntentClientSecret);
                stripe.confirmPayment(this, confirmParams);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Handle the result of stripe.confirmPayment
        stripe.onPaymentResult(requestCode, data, new PaymentResultCallback(this));
    }

    public void goback(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    private static final class PayCallback implements Callback {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;
        PayCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                    Toast.makeText(
                            activity, "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
            );
        }
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull final Response response)
                throws IOException {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(() ->
                        Toast.makeText(
                                activity, "Error: " + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                );
            } else {
                activity.onPaymentSuccess(response);
            }
        }
    }

    private void onPaymentSuccess(@NonNull final Response response) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> responseMap = gson.fromJson(
                Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string(),
                type

        );
        paymentIntentClientSecret = responseMap.get("clientSecret");
    }
    private final class PaymentResultCallback
            implements ApiResultCallback<PaymentIntentResult> {
        @NonNull private final WeakReference<PaymentPageActivity> activityRef;
        PaymentResultCallback(@NonNull PaymentPageActivity activity) {
            activityRef = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull PaymentIntentResult result) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            PaymentIntent paymentIntent = result.getIntent();
            PaymentIntent.Status status = paymentIntent.getStatus();
            if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                // Payment completed successfully
                /*
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment completed",
                        gson.toJson(paymentIntent)
                );

                 */

                String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ads");
                final DatabaseReference update = rootRef.child(uid);
                final DatabaseReference rootRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("card_information");
                final DatabaseReference update1 = rootRef1.child(uid);


update1.child("card_number").setValue(cardInputWidget.getCard().component1());
update1.child("cvc").setValue(cardInputWidget.getCard().component2());
update1.child("expiration_month").setValue(cardInputWidget.getCard().component3());
update1.child("expiration_year").setValue(cardInputWidget.getCard().component4());
update1.child("postal_code").setValue(cardInputWidget.getCard().getAddressZip());


                Intent intent = getIntent();

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


                String get_key = extras.getString("id-key");

                update.child(get_key).child("status").setValue("Paid");



                Intent intent2=new Intent(PaymentPageActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            } else if (status == PaymentIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                // Payment failed – allow retrying using a different payment method
                activity.displayAlert(
                        "Payment failed",
                        Objects.requireNonNull(paymentIntent.getLastPaymentError()).getMessage()
                );
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
            final PaymentPageActivity activity = activityRef.get();
            if (activity == null) {
                return;
            }
            // Payment request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method
            activity.displayAlert("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void displayAlert(@NonNull String title,
                              @Nullable String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to leverage CardInputWidget or CardMultiline from the Android SDK instead of the broken up components, those are internal components.

Comment: wow. I was trying to customize it because I don't like the design of the way the CardInputWidget set up and the cardMultiline and I thought I was able to do customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and here is the code:

```
 CardInputWidget cardInputWidget = new CardInputWidget(this);
            cardInputWidget.setCardNumber("4242424242424242");
            cardInputWidget.setCvcCode("546");
            cardInputWidget.setExpiryDate(5,22);
            cardInputWidget.setPostalCodeRequired(false);


 PaymentMethodCreateParams params = cardInputWidget.getPaymentMethodCreateParams();
```

and you can customize your layout as you like.

Comment: Ben thanks for the answer, but I have that set in my code. How will I customize it?

Comment: get the cardnumber from `CardNumberEditText` and cvccode from `CvcEditText` and expirydate from `ExpiryDateEditText` !!

Comment: what about the card holder name?